Distributed Computing with XML-RPC in Python
I need to create two Python programs, Server.py and Client.py. Server.py should register x procedures that the client will be able to call. It will then bind to the address "localhost" and port 8000.
Server.py should support the following procedures:

"name" returns the name of the server which is passed on the command line during server invocation

"help" returns a list of procedures that the server supports

"servertime" returns the current time at the server in 24 hour format

add(x,y) returns the sum of x and y

sub(x,y) returns x - y

mult(x, y) returns x * y

div(x, y) returns x / y, including handling a divide by zero scenario


For Client.py, the client connects to the server using the server's address and the port the server is listening on (in this case, localhost and 8000). x and y will equal 8 and 6, and will be then pass on to those different functions listed in Server.py
This is the code I have for both programs:
Server.py
import sys
import time
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

host_address = sys.argv[1]
host_port = sys.argv[2]
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((str(hostAddress), int(port)))

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

def mult(x, y):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print(x + " divided by " + y + " is infinity.")

def name():
    return hostAddress

def helpFunc():
    return server.system_listMethods()

def servertime():
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

server.register_function(name)
server.register_function(helpFunc)
server.register_function(add)
server.register_function(servertime)
server.register_function(sub)
server.register_function(mult)
server.register_function(div)
server.serve_forever()

Client.py
import xmlrpc.client
import sys
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

host_address = sys.argv[1]
host_port = sys.argv[2]
x = sys.argv[3]
y = sys.argv[4]

URI = "http://" + host_address + ":" + host_port
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URI)

print('{} + {} is {}'.format(x, y, str(proxy.add(x, y))))
print('{} - {} is {}'.format(x, y, str(proxy.sub(x, y))))
print('{} * {} is {}'.format(x, y, str(proxy.mult(x, y))))
print('{} / {} is {}'.format(x, y, str(proxy.div(x, y))))
print(proxy.name())
print(proxy.helpFunc())
print(proxy.servertime())

When I run the programs, however, I get the following error:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it

Could I please get some help on this?

for starters, change: server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((str(hostAddress), int(port))) to server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((str(host_address), int(host_port))).  Show your command lines used to invoke ... (PS: this starts up on a mac - though there's issues with the calls )

Did this. It is still running the same error

hum, sry to hear that, check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314169/numerous-connectionrefusederror-winerror-10061-in-python-requests and search within SO for other mentions of this error. NB: I have no experience of Windows so don't want to venture suggestions purely based on speculation/assumptions

Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771510/7909604
